Show that if $f$ is convex then $g(x)=\dfrac{1}{2h}\int_{x-h}^{x+h}f(t)dt$ is convex.
Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ a convex and continuous fonction. Let $g(x)= \dfrac{1}{2h}\displaystyle\int_{x-h}^{x+h}f(t)dt$. Show that $g$ is convex.
I showed that $g'(x) = \dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}$ and then I tried to use the convexity of $f$ to show that $g'$ is increasing but I didn't succeed.
Thanks for your help!

Hint: $g(x)= \frac{1}{2h}\int_{-h}^{+h}f(x+t)dt$

In general, if $(x,t) \mapsto \phi(x,t)$ is convex in $x$, then $x \mapsto \int \phi(x,t) dt$ is convex. This follows more or less immediately from the definition of convexity. The previous comment shows how to express the integral in this form.

By the change of variables $\xi=t-x$ in the integral we have that
$$g(x)=\frac{1}{2h}\int_{-h}^hf(x+\xi)\,\mathrm{d}\xi.$$
From this we have that, for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and any $\lambda\in(0,1)$,
\begin{align*}
g(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)
&=\frac{1}{2h}\int_{-h}^hf(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y+\xi)\,\mathrm{d}\xi \\
&=\frac{1}{2h}\int_{-h}^hf(\lambda (x+\xi)+(1-\lambda)(y+\xi))\,\mathrm{d}\xi \\
&\leq\frac{1}{2h}\int_{-h}^h\bigl(\lambda f(x+\xi)+(1-\lambda)f(y+\xi)\bigr)\,\mathrm{d}\xi \\
&=\lambda\frac{1}{2h}\int_{-h}^hf(x+\xi)\,\mathrm{d}\xi+(1-\lambda)\frac{1}{2h}\int_{-h}^hf(y+\xi)\,\mathrm{d}\xi \\
&=\lambda g(x)+(1-\lambda)g(y),
\end{align*}
where we used that $f$ is convex for the inequality. It follows that $g$ is convex.
